# rather and past events

Tags: grammar

in a movie a hitman gives a man's wife two choices:

- A "he could lose his toe"
- B "he can lose two front teeth"

... and the woman goes for the toe choice.

when then hitman leaves the room to grab a knife for the procedure the man yells at his wife: "What the hell, Jessica!"

His wife replies: "Would you have rather he would take your teeth?"

**why doesn't the woman say: "Would you rather he..." without "have"?
I know she is talking about something imaginary in the past but shouldn't the sentence include a verb in the past participle form with "have"?**

for example we say "I would rather have seen it" or "I would rather you hadn't talked".

Comment: Is she a pedantic professor or a human? Dialog works better when it sounds more like humans than textbooks.

Comment: No, she's talking about a possible future event: in the narrative, the thug is preparing to carry out the act. 'Would you rather he knocked out your teeth?' is standard (Englishwise).

Comment: Certainly it's the second *would* which is odd in British English. It could be more standard in American English.

Comment: What movie is this?

Comment: I assume the screenwriter has noticed that people often speak ungrammatically at times of stress, and as Yosef Baskin says, is aiming for verisimilitude. But I guess the real question isn't "why does she say that?", it's "what would be grammatically correct here?"

Comment: I think the question is looking for the sort of technical analysis contained in Claire Bush's answer, but I sympathize with the comments. I think a more grammatical question in natural speech would be "Would you rather lose a toe?" Moving toward the pedantry-end of the spectrum a bit, she could ask "Would you rather have him take a toe?"

Comment: If the action is all in the past, she might ask "Would you have preferred to lose a toe?", the past sense of the word "prefer" seeming natural, while "have rathered to" just cannot be right.

Answer (score 0):

The situation is anchored in the present with another future about to transform into a nasty present tense in the other room. There is no past tense.

The conversation as written is in present tense.  The use of "could" as in he could lose two toes" is a modal auxiliary -could as a hypothetical action pointing to, in this story, an unpleasant choice offered in the present and to be executed in the future.

It is pointing to an action that might happen in the future. The same is true for can lose two teeth.

What the woman says is not at all grammatical.  Is it possible that the woman is not a native speaker of English?

Instead of this: Would you have rather he would take your teeth?, she can say, "Would you rather he knock out your teeth?  Would you rather...is a formal construct.  Would rather is a modal auxiliary followed by the infinitive knock but without the particle 'to'. Would you rather I knock out your teeth?  Would you rather he/she/knock out your teeth.

Another way to keep "have" in the mix is this:  Would you rather have your teeth knocked out?  This sentence is a passive voice construction following the same rule as I presented above: Would rather is a modal auxiliary followed by the infinitive have but without the particle 'to, and then the addition of the past participle of 'knock'- knocked.  This sentence has one more bit of language:  to have something done.  For example:  I'm going to the dentist to have my teeth cleaned.

I think the woman made a serious mistake though.  You can always get false teeth, toes?  Even one toe is a loss.

Comment: Of course lots of people retain all their toes for the entire journey through life, while teeth are a shakier proposition. So mathematics might suggest that the loss of teeth deserves some sort of discount.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modernish trend that might be in response to the dwindling subjunctive construction. The perfect marker *have* has been acquiring some new duties. It now is used to mark counterfactual items regardless of aspect. It also has a habit of being used redundantly when the counterfactual item is in fact in perfect aspect.

> Would you have rather he would take your teeth?

To me, this works out to be

Would you have rather [it had been decided] he would take your teeth?

The difference between the sentences with and without *have* is that with *have*, it is expressly counterfactual, and without it, it sounds like he could still choose. Counterfactuality inhabits the past and present. There aren't any counterfactual futures.

From *Meaning and the English Verb* by Geoffrey N. Leech, section 179:

https://books.google.com/books?id=ISisAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT197&ots=Ntum2cOAdQ&dq=%22double%20marking%22%20perfect%20aspect&pg=PT198#v=onepage&q=%22double%20marking%22%20perfect%20aspect&f=false

> Past hypothetical meaning and the use of modals is one of the most difficult areas of English, not only for non-native speakers, but also for native speakers. It may be partly as a result of this that the language shows signs of confused and fluctuating usage, especially in the area of "hypothetical past time". We have noted that a hypothetical past expressed by a Past Perfect in a dependent clause is strongly associated with a "contrary to fact" meaning. Also "contrary to fact" are some secondary modals + Perfect in main clauses: we notice this with shouldn't, needn't, and might + Perfect. ... There seems to be a growing tendency, in fact, to associate a Perfect after a secondary modal purely with "contrary to fact" meaning rather than past time. On this basis, we can suggest why speakers sometimes produce sentences like this:
>
> *I would have enjoyed meeting you and Maria next Thursday, but I'm afraid I will be away.*
>
> In this case, the imaginary event of "meeting you and Maria" is
> located in the future, rather than in the past, so it is only the
> "contrary to fact" meaning that is applicable: the past meaning of the
> Perfect seems to have been lost.   Another area of confusion, in
> spoken English, is the "double marking" of hypothetical meaning in
> examples such as these:
>
> If they'd *have arrived* yesterday, they'd *have seen* the place at
> its best.
>
> By "double marking", I mean the *if*-clause has two forms
> signalling the same meaning. The expected construction is *If they'd
> arrived*. ... This is supported by the occasional (growing)
> occurrence of "pure" hypothetical *would* in dependent clauses: a
> construction generally supposed to be "unEnglish".